# recording audio on android 6.0+ while whatapp is active

Tags: java, android, whatsapp

I am using a simple icecast streaming app.

https://github.com/fatihsokmen/android-icecast-broadcast

I want it to continue streaming even when applications such as whatapp are active.

I do not want to capture the conversation just continue streaming from the one device.

any idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try Follwoing way ,

1. First Check whatsapp is Open or not

   - For this Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/23562032/3416642
   - You have to create a service to check whats app is open or not
     if open start new service.
2. Create service to record Audio

   - Here is example how to record audio using Service.

   public class AudioRecordService extends Service {

   ```
       private static final String TAG = AudioRecordService.class.getSimpleName();


       MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;

       private ShardPref mPref;


       public void onCreate() {
           Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: ");
           mPref = new ShardPref(this);
           super.onCreate();

       }

       @Override
       public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
           Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand: ");
           MediaRecorderReady();
           return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
       }

       public void onDestroy() {
           Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy: ");
           if (mediaRecorder != null) {
               mediaRecorder.stop();
           }

           super.onDestroy();

       }


       @Override
       public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
           return null;
       }

       private String getFilename() {


           File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + FolderUtils.AUDIO_FOLDER_NAME + File.separator);
           if (!root.exists()) {
               root.mkdirs();
           }
           String filename = Utils.getAudioName(Constant.AUDIO_PATH);
           mPref.setCurrentAudioFileName(filename);

           return (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + filename);


       }

       public void MediaRecorderReady() {
           mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
           mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
           mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
           mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
           mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());
           Log.e(TAG, "Media Recording Audio");
           try {
               mediaRecorder.prepare();
               mediaRecorder.start();
           } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }


   }
   ```

Note : Please handle require permission